# WaitForSingleObject always returns WAIT_FAILED

Tags: delphi, winapi

Why `WaitForSingleObject` function in this case always returns `WAIT_FAILED`?

```
function KillProcessByWindowName(WindowTitle:string):boolean;
var WindowHandle:HWND;
    PID: DWORD;
    ProcessHandle,WaitStatus:cardinal;
begin
  Result:=false;
  WindowHandle:=FindWindow(nil,PChar(WindowTitle));
  if WindowHandle<>0 then
  begin
    GetWindowThreadProcessID(WindowHandle,@PID);
    if PID<>0 then
    begin
      ProcessHandle:=OpenProcess(PROCESS_TERMINATE,False,PID);
      if ProcessHandle>0 then
      begin
        TerminateProcess(ProcessHandle,0);
        repeat
          WaitStatus:=WaitForSingleObject(ProcessHandle,100);
        until WaitStatus<>WAIT_TIMEOUT;

        if WaitStatus=WAIT_OBJECT_0 then Result:=true
      end;
      CloseHandle(ProcessHandle);
    end;
  end;

end;
```

Comment: Have you checked the result from `TerminateProcess`?

Comment: If I put GetLastError after loop I get value 5 (ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)

Comment: Check the result from `TerminateProcess` first. and then check for last error (if any). In any case you need to add `SYNCHRONIZE` flag in order to wait for the handle.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you might lack the SYNCHRONIZE privilege for the process you want to terminate.
in order to verify that:

1. create a process P inside your app and grab its handle
2. while still in the same application, call KillProcessByWindowName() on P

This will succeed because you have the SYNCHRONIZE privilege on a process you have created.
(If not - this is a different issue)

Comment: ProcessHandle:=OpenProcess(SYNCHRONIZE + PROCESS_TERMINATE,False,PID); 
This seems to work. BTW Should I use "or" instead of "+" here?

Comment: @Atak: Yes, always use `or`. The constants might have a bit in common, in which case `+` will fail badly. Always use `or` when you want to combine flags.

Comment: Why is it "or" instead of  for example "and" ? This seems to be illogical at least for me.

Comment: @Atak_Snajpera: Learn about [bitwise operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation). For instance, `00001000 or 00000010 = 00001010`. Clearly you have combined the two flags. On the other hand, `00001000 and 00000010 = 00000000` which is very much not a combination of the flags. But you really must learn the basics of bitwise operators, for instance by reading the linked Wikipedia page. In practice, to combine flags or to add a new flag, you use `or`: `FSettings or RUN_FAST`. To see if a flag is on, extract the bit using `and` and test for non-zero: `FSettings and RUN_FAST <> 0`.